# delete section at indexPath swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have an array which populates a table view - myPosts.

The first row of the table view is not part of the array.

Each row is its own section (with its own custom footer)

I am trying to perform a delete with the following code:

```
func tableView(profileTableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
                myPosts?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section - 1)
                profileTableView.beginUpdates()
                let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
                indexSet.addIndex(indexPath.section - 1)
                profileTableView.deleteSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                profileTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                profileTableView.endUpdates()
                ...
                WS Call 
                ...
            }
}
```

And the log is reporting the following:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an 
>           existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that 
>       section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from 
>       that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out 
>       of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Obviously the issue is related to 0 moved in, 0 moved out but I don't understand why that is? or what the solution would be?

Number of sections in tableView is as follows:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if self.myPosts == nil
        {

            return 1
        }
        return self.myPosts!.count + 1
    }
```

Comment: bear in mind, after you have deleted the section at index 0, the section at index 1 will become the new section at index 0; therefore you need to be aware of reflecting that in your _data-source_ as well (which we don't know anything about), and you need to do something with the rows as well.

Comment: @holex my data source is updated in the Webservice call that's commented out there. What else do i need to do with the rows apart from deleteRowsAtIndexPath which is in there already?

Comment: you __must finish__ updating your local _data-source_ before you call the `–endUpdates` method; otherwise you are doomed.

Comment: @holex and the line: myPosts?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section - 1) does not handle updating the data source?!

Comment: on the other hand, logically if the section's number _are not changing_ after "delete" (because you will show 1 section anyway after the last one is "deleted"), you must not call the `-deleteSections:withRowAnimation:` method, you just need to call the `-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` method only; because __the section's number will be the same__ after "deleting" it; you just want to get it updated.

Comment: @holex switching out deleteSections to reloadSections is not making a difference. Same error appearing in the log. Also I'm not sure what you mean by section's number. The section's index or the section count?

Comment: please, read some tutorials about that first, it is not a simple _switching from this method to that_, it is much bigger logically than it could be explained in a short comment if you have not got the basic concept of working with `UITableView`, I'm afraid. :( I could highlight where you need to start finding the solution only at, but it is not suitable for tutorials.

Comment: I think the problem is calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` after `deleteSections` wasn't calling `deleteSections` enough?

Comment: @holex thanks for your help but everything you've said thus far apart from reloading instead of deleting, I thought I had covered. i.e. you said I need to update the datasource, I pointed to the line where I believed to be doing so. You said I also need to do 'something' with the rows. i also asked if the line 'deleteRowsAtIndexPath' was the handling you were referring to? I have never worked with 'reloading' sections as opposed to deletingSections. But if we are to stick with deleting, I still don't understand the issue. And I'm still not sure if by section number you meant index or count

Comment: @Ismail thank you, that was it! :)

Comment: @user2363025, that is the exact reason why I recommended to walk through some tutorials; but if you have found the solution in changing the lines' order randomly, that is still good for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the answer is just removing the line that deletes the rows.

So the code is here to delete:

```
 func tableView(profileTableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            myPosts?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section - 1)
            profileTableView.beginUpdates()
            let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
            indexSet.addIndex(indexPath.section - 1)
            profileTableView.deleteSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
           // profileTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            profileTableView.endUpdates()
            ...
            WS Call 
            ...
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 13):

Updated the answer for **Swift 4.2** and made a few additional tweaks:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        myPosts?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section - 1)
        let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: indexPath.section)
        profileTableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
        // Perform any follow up actions here
    }
}
```

The use of [`beginUpdates()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates) and `endUpdates()` is not necessary, since you are only doing one action that contains animation. If you are doing 2 or more, than it is worth combining them to get a fluid effect.

Also, this makes use of the Swift 3 classes, by doing away with the `NSMutableIndexSet()` call, which would require a conversion now to work with the `deleteSections()` call.